# Inverse of number in binary

Tags: algorithm

Suppose we have some arbitrary positive number `x`.

Is there a method to represent its inverse in binary or `x`'s inverse is `1/x` - how does one express that in binary?

e.g. `x=5 //101`
`x`'s inverse is `1/x`, it's binary form is ...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd find it the same way you would in decimal form: [**long division**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division).

There is no shortcut just because you are in another base, although long division is significantly simpler.

[**Here**](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs1104/BuildingBlocks/divide.030.html) is a very nice explanation of long division applied to binary numbers.

[image: ld]

Although, just to let you know, most floating-point systems on today's machines do very fast division for you.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the only practical way to "express in binary" an arbitrary fraction is as a pair of integers, numerator and denominator -- "floating point", the most commonly used (and hardware supported) binary representation of non-integer numbers, can represent exactly on those fractions whose denominator (when the fraction is reduced to the minimum terms) is a power of two (and, of course, only when the fixed number of bits allotted to the representation is sufficient for the number we'd like to represent -- but, the latter limitation will also hold for *any* fixed-size binary representation, including the simplest ones such as integers).

Answer (score 1):

```
0.125          = 0.001b
0.0625         = 0.0001b
0.0078125      = 0.0000001b
0.00390625     = 0.00000001b
0.00048828125  = 0.00000000001b
0.000244140625 = 0.000000000001b
----------------------------------
0.199951171875 = 0.001100110011b
```

Knock yourself out if you want higher accuracy/precision.

Answer (score 1):

Another form of multiplicative inverse takes advantage of the modulo nature of integer arithmetic as implemented on most computers; in your case the 32 bit value 
11001100110011001100110011001101 (-858993459 signed int32 or 3435973837 unsigned int32)  when multiplied by 5 equals 1 (mod 4294967296). Only values which are coprime with the power of two the modulo operates on have such multiplicative inverses.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the first few bits of a binary fraction number, this trick will give you those bits: `(2 << 31) / x`. But don't use this trick on any real software project. (because it is rough, inaccurate and plainly wrong way to represent the value)